# All fields required in List of objects ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, list, validation, unobtrusive-validation

For example I have code like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
   public string Value1 {get; set;}
   public string Value2 {get; set;}
}
```

How I could make all fields in every object in list required, but show only one validation message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
   [Required]
   public string Value1 {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public string Value2 {get; set;}
}
```

But I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, try to insert some more details, like the HTML part

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**